# How to avoid using multiple regex.replace

Tags: c#, regex

Goal is to take in a text file, normalize it down to only having all upper case letters, remove all special characters, and turn any new line into a single space.

This is my current messy code to do it, and as far as I can tell it does work.

```
public string readTextFile(string fileName)
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex("[^A-Z ]");
    string txtFile = File.ReadAllText(fileName).ToUpper();

    txtFile = Regex.Replace(txtFile, @"\s+", " ", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    return rgx.Replace(txtFile, "");
}
```

Looking for anyone to help clean this code up, improve efficiency, and possibly combine my regex statements to one.

Comment: you can't really combine them because they are doing two different operations.

Comment: do you call this messy?! this isnt really messy if you good format your code as i did it for you ;) you can also define regexes behind each other to make it less seem messy

Comment: what is `fullBook` here?

Comment: *turn any new line into a single space* - `\s+` matches *1 or more any whitespace*. If you need to match newlines only, use `[\r\n]+`. How many files do you handle? 1, 10, 100000? If more than a hundred, I suggest that you should avoid declaring the Regex object every time, declare it outside the method (best as `private static readonly` field).

Comment: see about [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) override replace method

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your regex, and use [Replace method with MatchEvaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx) like this

```
public string readTextFile(string fileName)
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex("");
    string txtFile = File.ReadAllText(fileName).ToUpper();

    txtFile = Regex.Replace(txtFile, @"(\s+)|([^A-Z ])", 
                m=> m.Groups[2].Success ? string.Empty : " ",
                RegexOptions.Multiline);
    return txtFile;
}
```